# Get data from associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 entities: `Product, Object, Key`

```
Product had many Objects
Objects has many Products
Product And Object has many Keys
```

How can I get for a Product all the Objects with their Keys? An Object can have many Keys. Also Keys can be of two types   `(:type = 1, :type = 2)`

Currently I have a working code, but there are to many loops, and I want to learn different ways of doing these things

Comment: Why have you tagged this rails, rails 3, 3.1 and 4... ? Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I am using rails 4

Comment: It would be better to rename your `Object` model to `Item` or something like that for avoid possible conflicts with ruby `Object` class.

Comment: This is just an example.

Comment: This example is a bit vague, could you show some more of your code? I.e. the loops that you're talking about.

Comment: well first I <%render @Objects%> where @object=product.objects, @object.where(type=1).each do keys, and @object.where(type=2).each do keys_t2 ...

Answer (score 0):

objects is a very bad name for a table in a rails app

```
class Product
   # thats a table with product_id and object_id and key_id
   has_many :product_item_relations 
   has_many :items, :through => :object_relations
end 

class Item
  has_many :product_item_relations
  has_many :products, :through => :item_relations
end

class ProductItemRelation
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :key_elements
end

class KeyElement
  belongs_to :product_item_relation
end
```

and to request the key elements

```
ProductItemRelation.where( :product_id => pid, :item_id => iid ).key_elements
```

Comment: is not working, PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column key_elements.product_item_relation_id does not exist

Comment: a typo in KeyElements - belongs_to without plural

Comment: I typed the s by mistake, the error is because I don't have the product_item_relation_id column in the KeyElement table.